# Photo Attachment's Feature For Some Mail Servers

Tags: malware, attacks, virus, known-vulnerabilities, google

You already know google started new service which is related to gmail.

http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2013/11/attachments-in-gmail-now-with-power-of.html

When we send new mail to friends.If it contains any attachment(photo etc ) , photos will open directly with mail.

Is there any security problem with this subject?

Can I easily understand mail is opened or not?

What can attacker do with this feature and malicious code?

Comment: You really should be more specific with your questions. "Is there any security problem with [email attachments]" is extremely vague. —— What's your specific concern?

Comment: For example attacker combined jpeg and malicious code.Then sent to my mail address. I just opened the mail. In this situation what can attacker do ?
Is it still vague?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been 2 recent changes to Gmail:

**1.**

Gmail will show images by default, proxied through Google's servers (and ["checked for known viruses or malware"](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2013/12/images-now-showing.html)). If there's an exploitable vulnerability that can be embedded in a JPEG image, we'd probably have been screwed a long time ago since any website can also show images without any virus checks being run on them.

The changes [probably don't affect open tracking](http://blog.mailchimp.com/how-gmails-image-caching-affects-open-tracking/). But you won't be able to see user IP addresses / user agent strings.

**2.**

Gmail will provide more options with regard to saving attachments. This should also not change anything since 1) old-style "open attachment" will still be available 2) attachments are [scanned for viruses anyway](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/25760?hl=en). Attachments are parsed (for previews etc) server-side, so a (for example) PDF with malicious scripts won't affect users any more than with the old "trick user into opening a malicious file" method.